# JNI NoClassDefFoundError in springboot executable jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-native-interface, noclassdeffounderror

I have springboot application which is connecting to client shared dynamic library using **jni**.

There is one **callback method **which is registered to dll using ine register function.
This method is invoked on some events from dll.

When executed as java application from intellij, this works fine but when executed **as jar **and when this callback method is invoked its throwing **NoClassDefFoundError ** as below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/Sample
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.Sample
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java: 424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

By default springboot puts all classes inside BOOT-INF folder.

When I manually modified jar and added this class outside BOOT-INF i.e at rootLevel it worked.
Like below:

```
 BOOT-INF
 com
 META-INF
 org
```

In above snippet com is directory inside which Sample class was present under subpackage test.

springboot version used: **2.3.6.RELEASE**

Using **springboot-maven-plugin** to create executable jar

Comment: Does this help? [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: Abra: May be it can help but how can we do that ? You mean while executing jar via command line
These classes are inside one of dependency jar an ld also being used by another classes.                             If we add them again , will it cause any conflicts?